# How to assign if(isset($authUrl)) to Image inside div

Tags: php, html

I been able to modify code for "**login using Google-plus API**" successfully & working well on localhost.

I am trying to assign `$authUrl` (gplus-login.php) values to another PHP file "trackorder.php" image (inside div tag).

**Trackorder.php** file where I want to place **$authUrl** value

```
    <div style="margin-left:50px;">
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/Google-button.png" style="width:200px; height:35px;"></a>
    </div>
```

**gplus-login.php**

```
 <?php
 require_once 'src/apiClient.php';
 require_once 'src/contrib/apiPlusService.php';

 session_start();

 $client = new apiClient();
 $client->setApplicationName("My Project");
 $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
 $plus = new apiPlusService($client);

 if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) 
  {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
  }

  if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
  {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  }

  if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) 
  {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  }

  if ($client->getAccessToken()) 
  {
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public',$optParams);

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
   $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  } 
  else 
  {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl(); 
  }
 ?>

 <div>
 <?php if(isset($me))
 {  
 $_SESSION['gplusdata']=$me;
 header("location: home.php");
 } 
 ?>

 <?php
 if(isset($authUrl)) 
 {
 print "<a class='login' href="$authUrl">Google Login</a>";
 } 
 else 
 {
  print "<a class='logout' href='trackorder.php?logout'>Logout</a>";
 }
 ?><br/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include the Trackorder.php and set your dynamic variables prior to the include.

```
<?php
if(!isset($authUrl)) {
$authUrl = 'trackorder.php?logout';
$authLabel = 'Logout';
$authClass = 'logout';
} else {
$authLabel = 'Google Login';
$authClass = 'login';
}
include('Trackorder.php');
?>
```

and for Trackorder.php

```
<div style="margin-left:50px;">
    <a href="<?= $authUrl; ?>" class="<?= $authClass; ?>"><?= $authLabel; ?>
      <img src="images/Google-button.png" style="width:200px; height:35px;"></a>
</div>
```

Not sure what you want to do with the image in the link.

If you only want the Trackorder.php file to be present for login, just move the include to inside the else and revert the initial if clause to spit out the logout link.